# Single Post Templates Doubt

Tags: templates, template-hierarchy

While I was reading template [hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/).

The single post template file is used to render a single post. WordPress uses the following path:

**single-{post-type}-{slug}.php** – (Since 4.4) First, WordPress looks for a template for the specific post. For example, if post type is product and the post slug is dmc-12, WordPress would look for **single-product-dmc-12.php**.

**single-{post-type}.php** – If the post type is product, WordPress would look for **single-product.php**.

I am slightly confused the above two in bold face do they differ technically somehow or It is Just the matter of convention while creating Templates for Posts.

Comment: They do not differ technically. If `single-{post-type}-{slug}.php` does not exist then WordPress will load `single-{post-type}.php`. If you want the product page for a single product to look different than the other product pages, then you would create `single-{post-type}-{slug}.php` so that only that one product page is affected

Comment: Didn't get this part - "**If you want the product page for a single product to look different than the other product pages, then you would create single-{post-type}-{slug}.php so that only that one product page is affected**" you mean product archive page and product single page?

Comment: These templates are for product single pages

Comment: Oh I See you mean to say one will be default and another will be available as an option to choose while creating product pages?

Comment: No it will not be available as an option. These files exist in your theme directory and the template that loads is determined by the following: If you have a product with slug of `dmc-12`, then WordPress will first look for a file called `single-product-dmc-12.php` in the theme directory. If it finds it it will use that template when creating the page. If this file does not exist, then it will look for a file called `single-product.php` in the theme directory. If that file does not exist, then WordPress will look for a file called `single.php` in the theme directory.

Comment: Can you write all this in answer so that I can accept this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

They do not differ technically. These files exist in your theme directory and the template that loads is determined by the following: If you have a product with slug of dmc-12, then WordPress will first look for a file called `single-product-dmc-12.php` in the theme directory. If it finds it it will use that template when creating the page. If this file does not exist, then it will look for a file called `single-product.php` in the theme directory. If that file does not exist, then WordPress will look for a file called `single.php` in the theme directory.